# Input Filter by number not working

Tags: javascript, filter

I have a filter which must return what I've entered in "input"

```js
    filterAmount(e) {
      var value = e.target.value;
    
      this.setState({
        filteredAmounts: !value
          ? false
          : this.props.items.filter(function(item) {
            return item.income_amount ;
          })
      })
    }
```

```html
<input onChange={this.filterAmount.bind(this)} type='text' placeholder='amount search'></input>
```

But, now when I enter any value, my table with results disappears. For example. I have value with "0" I entered "0" to input and all table disappears. What is the correct way to return to filter?

[image]

I use it with react, there full code https://plnkr.co/edit/UGXuK1AMvibVRw1zvIfD?p=catalogue

Comment: How looks `props.items` ?

Comment: add image, to post, please check

Comment: Have a look at my answer.

Comment: Not helps, now filter not working

Comment: You are not using `value` inside `filter`? Is there any `item` where `income_amount != 0`? I assume `setState` is updating ur table

Comment: No, now server returns me only with "0" . So when enter "2" I no need display enything. And when I enter "0" I need display all. Just filters by value

Comment: change to `this.props.items.filter(function(item) {
        return true ;
      })` and tell me if you receive all the results.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai  Nothing happens. filter not working

Comment: `var value = e.target.value;` gets the correct value ?

Comment: `this.props.items.filter(function(item) {
            console.log(item.income_amount);
            return true;
          })`. Tell me what you receive in `console` in this case.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai Any data I entered console.log returtns 0.

Comment: It's correct because I have obj only with "0: I consoled log for value it returns me corect value

Comment: `filteredItems` works for you ?

Comment: yes, it works fine

Comment: return  item.income_amount == value ; helps

Answer (score 0):

```
  return  item.income_amount == value ; Helps
```